# How to add an object inside an array of objects in MongoDB using a query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that have an array of objects called "messages". Each object in the "messages" array represents a message with various fields like "messageId", "date", "is_from_user", etc.

I would like to write a MongoDB query to add a new object to the "messages" array based on the "conversation_id" and "messageId". Here's an example of a document:

```
{
  "_id": "91XXXXXXXXXXXX_botXXXXXXXXXXX-v3",
  "bot_id": "bot-template-v3",
  "version": "3.0",
  "channel": "WHATSAPP",
  "name": "AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "user_id": "919XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "conversation_id": "919XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "last_modified": {
    "$date": "2023-07-19T04:03:24.584Z"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "messageId": "ABEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-07-17T10:33:18.291Z"
      },
      "is_from_user": true,
      "sentiment": "positive",
      "from_kb": false,
      "intent": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "is_conversation_incomplete": false,
      "type": "text",
      "message": "hi",
      "content_url": null,
      "content": null,
      "suggested_actions": null,
      "activityId": "ABEGkZ**********************"
    },
    {
      "messageId": "gBEGkZIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4",
      "date": {
        "$date": "2023-07-17T10:33:19.297Z"
      },
      "is_from_user": false,
      "sentiment": "positive",
      "from_kb": false,
      "intent": "",
      "is_conversation_incomplete": false,
      "type": "interactive",
      "message": "[interactive]",
      "content_url": null,
      "content": {
        "type": "button",
        "header": {
          "type": "image",
          "image": {
            "link": "https:*************************************"
          }
        },
        "body": {
          "text": "Hey **************************"
        },
        "action": {
          "buttons": [
            {
              "type": "reply",
              "reply": {
                "id": "Request a Demo",
                "title": "Request a Demo"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "suggested_actions": null,
      "activityId": "ABEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
]
}
```

I want to add this new message object to the "messages" array of the document that matches the "conversation_id" and "messageId".

Could you please guide me on how to write the MongoDB query to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show some sample output documents to make the question clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 db.collection.updateOne(
      { conversation_id: "conversation ID here", "messages.messageId": "messageId here" },
      { $push: { messages: newMessage } }
    );
```

in this code it searches for a matching conversation_id and messageID and then  adds a newMessage to the messages array.